# Is there a difference in the impact of an upvote on a question, when the upvote comes from an answerer?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, up-votes

I believe that when a question gets upvoted, it gets more attention. But is there a difference to the impact of the upvote, when it comes from an answerer of that question?

I would assume some users who answer a question will then upvote it, so that it gets more attention, so that their answer will be seen more, giving it more of a chance to get upvotes. Which is why I ask.

Comment: Sort of. If I answer a question, that's a strong indication that it is interesting to me and thus worth an upvote. :-)

Comment: If an answerer really wanted to draw more attention, he could simply perform an action which bumps the question rather than upvoting.

Comment: this question have +2 and 2 answers... Nothing suspicious here :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All votes in the system have a weight of 1, regardless of who casts them.  Therefore a vote on a question by someone who answers it has exactly the same effect as one from someone who has no other interaction with the question at all.

I daresay there is some advantage to the answerer in upvoting the question, however this isn't gaming, nor is it given any different treatment by the system than other votes.

The only restriction on up/down votes, aside from reputation requirements, is that you can not vote for posts that you have created.

Answer (score 3):

No, They weight all the same.

I see how this tactical up-voting benefits the answerer, but I don't think it is a problem, lets review the possible scenarios:

- **Case bad (-1 or less) question:** it is likely to get deleted sooner or later and the answerer will lose the gained rep. In the worst scenario, it will survive but with very low attention (not achieving the goal of the up-voter).
- **Case average (0-1) question:** a random up-vote is not going to corrupt anything, very few people will click the question that wouldn't otherwise do this without the extra up-vote
- **Case good (2 or more) question:** it likely deserved the up-vote

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any impact, if the question is up-voted from a user who answered the question, as votes are anonymous. Even in the case who answered would add a comment saying "+1 [comment about why the user thinks the question is a good one]," you would never know if that user really up-voted the question.

If you know the user, or you think her/his opinion is trustable, then you could up-vote the question because his/her positive comment, but I don't think there are users who up-vote a question because a specific user left a positive comment, and answered. In some cases, the OP got a down-vote, and who answered got an up-vote.